# Make the game run in background

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

i wanted to create a simple game for android: my idea was a basic tycoon game. How can i make the player, for example, earning money during time even if the application is closed?
Thank you

Comment: when the app launches, check the current time and calculate how much money that accounts for… quite simple

Comment: You have to connect the game to a permanent server and control the variables with the help of database. The dateTime method is a bug because the user can manually increase and decrease the values ​​by adjusting the system time.

Comment: @KiynL it’s not necessarily a bug. It’s not resistant to clock manipulation, that’s correct, but maybe that is valid in specific scenarios. on the other hand, requiring an existing network connection may also be undesirable if it’s an offline-game. Simply calling it a „bug“ does not value the specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you should use System.DateTime.Now

This will give you the current time. All you have to do is subtract right now from the last time logged on. Then, multpily it by whatever money multiplier you had.

It moght get a little confusing based on hours and minutes and days, but you could just multiply days by how many seclnds are in a day, how many seconds are in an hour, and how many seconds are in a minute.

For more information, you should go to [this link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-get-system-time-in-unity.29667/) or [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-6.0).